# How to implement a database in python?

Tags: python, json, database

I want to create a database because I have a lot of items and each of them have a lot of attributes (a large dataset).

I first tried to create a JSON file for each tuple (attribute0, attribute1), but in a large scale it's impossible to do so. I then tried to split the data into multiple JSON files: one file per attribute with an unique id for each value, and one per tuple (attribute0, attribute1) using only the id of values. This worked better, but not that much better because each time I had to read a single value I had to read all the files. I also tried to split my files according to the hash of the values, the problem is now with the link between attributes. I cannot know where to find a specific index because I have to read every single file in order to find the good one.

Comment: So what's stopping you using an actual database?

Comment: It takes decades of man years to implement a DB.

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how to do that, beside the fact that I don't know how it's working, each time that I try to install a tool, it just won't install/won't communicate with python.

Comment: Database is a very heavy tool for a lot of users.  Please specify the data amount.  Maybe padas is what you need.

Comment: @WenlongLiu Would you say SQLite is heavy? Something's wrong...

Comment: Seriously, use an SQL database with `sqlite3`. It might take you a little time to learn, but it's powerful, lightweight, and really easy to use. You could always use text files or csv files instead, but... Well, it's less clean, and more difficult to maintain.

Comment: NO, SQLite is already implemented in Python, which is fine.  However, to make a DECENT database with acceptable requirements, such as safety, good speedy, clear table structure, etc.  This is pretty heavy.

Comment: @NadirGhoul I've read through your question multiple times and I really think SQLite would fit your needs. See my answer for more info.

Comment: @NadirGhoul I think you don't realize how complex it is to implement a proper, working database with even half-decent perfs and reliability. You will spend much less time solving your installation problems and learning to use some existing database system (SQL or else depending on your needs but everyone should know how to use a SQL database).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) database which can be setup in no time. Python's `sqlite3` module is really easy to use. The example below is from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html).

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE stocks
             (date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("INSERT INTO stocks VALUES ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)")
```

SQLite databases are good for data sizes of several GB. Since you were using JSON files before it sounds like this could solve your problem. This [article](http://engineeringterminal.com/computer-science/tutorials/sqlite-intro.html) gives a good intro to SQLite in general.

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider creating a new database system, since there are several very solid open source databases you could use. For your case, I recommend **tinydb**, a document database written in python, which simply uses a json file as storage.

https://github.com/msiemens/tinydb

Usage is very straightforward, and there's solid documentation. Here's a code sample from [the docs](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that shows typical usage:

```
>>> from tinydb import TinyDB, Query
>>> db = TinyDB('path/to/db.json')
>>> User = Query()
>>> db.insert({'name': 'John', 'age': 22})
>>> db.search(User.name == 'John')
[{'name': 'John', 'age': 22}]
```